# MDX to show customers who've placed and order this month but not this month last year

Tags: mdx, olap

I'm struggling with what the mdx would look like to return all customers who have placed an order this month but did not place an order ($0 sales) for the same month on the previous year.

I have Order Amount as a measure, CustomerId as a dimension, and Date as a dimension.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some code that you've already tried.

In `mdx` pseudo-code it would be like this:

```
  Except(  
    NonEmpty(
       {all members}                      //<<try a function that returns a set such as `.MEMBERS`
       ,(thisMonth, OrderAmountMeasure)   //<<the braces mean this is a tuple made up of two members
    )
   ,NonEmpty(
       {all members}                
       ,(equivMonthLastYear, OrderAmountMeasure)   //<<you could try the .LAG function to go back 12 months
    )
   )
```

Edit:

```
  iif(
     equivMonthLastYear = 0,
     null,
  Except(  
    NonEmpty(
       {all members}                      //<<try a function that returns a set such as `.MEMBERS`
       ,(thisMonth, OrderAmountMeasure)   //<<the braces mean this is a tuple made up of two members
    )
   ,NonEmpty(
       {all members}                
       ,(equivMonthLastYear, OrderAmountMeasure)   //<<you could try the .LAG function to go back 12 months
    )
   )
 )
```

Comment: Your pseudo-code works except for when there is no value in the cube for equivMonthLastYear.  In this case I don't want to return currentMonthThisYear.

Comment: @user5982263 you could add some additional logic via the `IIF` function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145994.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396